# How to solve equations with logarithms, like this: $ ax + b\log(x) + c=0$

Tags: logarithms, transcendental-equations

I encountered an equation of type $$ ax + b\log(x) + c=0$$ Here a, b, and c are constants. Does anyone know how to solve these type of equations? I guess this way:
$$\log(x)= \frac{c-ax}{b}$$
$$x= 10^{(c-ax)/b}$$
But I do not even know how to solve this too. Please help!

Comment: There are no closed form soltions for transcendental equations; so unless $a=0$ or $b=0$, you won't get a nice answer. But you can do it numerically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rewriting the equation gives
$$
ax+b\log(x)+c=0\\
ax+b\log\left(\frac abx\right)+c-b\log\left(\frac ab\right)=0\\
\frac abx+\log\left(\frac abx\right)+\frac cb-\log\left(\frac ab\right)=0\\
\color{#C00000}{(a/b)x}\,e^{\color{#C00000}{(a/b)x}}=(a/b)\,e^{-c/b}
$$
The [Lambert-W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) is the inverse of $xe^x$. Therefore,
$$
\color{#C00000}{(a/b)x}=\mathrm{W}\left((a/b)e^{-c/b}\right)
$$
and so
$$
x=(b/a)\mathrm{W}\left((a/b)e^{-c/b}\right)
$$

Comment: I did not understand how you used the lambert w function to get this. Shouldnt you have grouped x with it too? I mean the function is $xe^x$ right?

Comment: Sorry, i got it now. Didnt think this one though. Thanks @robjohn!

Comment: @Rohinb97: I added color to make it less confusing.

Comment: Thanks! This let me solve 2^n = n^100. One root is interesting because it's almost exactly 996 but not quite. By the way Matlab and Octave have a lambertw() function, convenient.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have a solution in the 'normal' functions.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function tells you all about it.
If you substitute $x=by/a$, you can rearrange to get $y+\log(y) = d$, so $ye^y=e^d$