# How to solve equations with both logarithms and square roots, like this: $ax+b\log(x)+c\sqrt{x}+d=0$

Tags: logarithms, radicals, transcendental-equations

I have an equation that looks like this:

$$ax+b \log(x)+c\sqrt x+d=0$$

I know that an equation without the $\sqrt x$ can be solved using the Lambert's W function ([How to solve equations with logarithms, like this: $ ax + b\log(x) + c=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433717/how-to-solve-equations-with-logarithms-like-this-ax-b-logx-c-0)). I am having trouble solving the equation with  $\sqrt x$, is there a (quasi) closed-form solution for this?

Comment: I can't prove it but, no, there is no closed-form, even with Lambert.

Comment: Do you have an example for the parameters $$a,b,c,d$$?

Comment: The exact equation is:
$8x +r \log (4x) +6 \sqrt x + 1=0$ 
where $r$ is a parameter.